# Kubernetes cloudnativepg operator local/nfs backups

Tags: kubernetes, postgresql

I wanted to test the cloudnativepg operator for a local cluster and would like to save the backups on a local dir. The problem is that the documentation only has information regarding cloud solutions https://cloudnative-pg.io/documentation/1.20/backup_recovery/ and I can't seem to make it work with directories. I know it is somewhat of a long shot since not many people use this operator. I was thinking of something like this:

```
62 │ backup:
63 │ │ barmanObjectStore:
64 │ │ │ destinationPath: /data
65 │ │ │ wal:
66 │ │ │ │ compression: gzip
67 │ │ │ │ encryption: AES256
68 │ │ │ data:
69 │ │ │ │ compression: gzip
70 │ │ │ │ encryption: AES256
71 │ │ │ │ immediateCheckpoint: false
72 │ │ │ │ jobs: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you could deploy minIO locally and then push the backups there. You can use [this](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/operations/install-deploy-manage/deploy-minio-single-node-single-drive.html#minio-snsd) link on how to deploy minio locally and then use the manifest provided by CloudnativePG to push and store the backups there.
[manifest_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu0Ku.png)